# calling web services with asynchImageView

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I am having a problem in calling web services when the image are being loaded in the tableView with AsynchImageView files .

Below are the steps of my problem:

1. I call the web service and when it returns the data i reload the UITableView and load all images with AsynchImageView . The web service returns url of images and some text data .
2. While the images are being loaded , if I call the same web service again then it runs for 30 seconds and then it times out without returning anything but after that time it works fine whenever I call it  .

Here is my code for calling services:

```
-(void)getUserNotificationsPage:(int)page CallBack:(getNotifications)callback{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
       @try {

            getNotificationsArrayResponseCallback=callback;


            NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?token=%@&page=%@",GET_USER_NOTIFICATIONS,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"token"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",page]]]];


            NSError *err;
            NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:nil error:&err];
            if(err){
                returnData=[NSMutableData data];
            }

            NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

 id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

        NSArray *returnArray=[json objectForKey:@"notifications"];

                getNotificationsArrayResponseCallback(returnArray,YES);

            });

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:LANGUAGE(@"Unknown error occurred") message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];


                getNotificationsArrayResponseCallback(nil,NO);

            });
        }        
     });
}
```

3. If I remove the code where the images are being loaded with asynchImageview then I call call the web service at any time and the response is fast at any time .

   ```
   AsynchImageView *userProfileImageView =[[AsynchImageView alloc] initWithFrameURLStringAndTag:CGRectMake(5, 215, 70, 70) :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SERVER_URL,"some url" ];

   [userProfileImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

   [userProfileImageView loadImageFromNetwork];

   [cell addSubview:userProfileImageView];
   ```

As you can see if I comment the line

```
[userProfileImageView loadImageFromNetwork];
```

then I can call the web service any number of times and the response is quick but when the asynchimage view is loading the images and then i call the service then it will time out for that time only . For further calling service works fine .

I think this is the issue with threading or calling serveral url requests at the same time .

Answer (score 2):

is this the class you are using? [AsynchImageView](https://github.com/dazza222/GetPix/blob/master/GetPix/AsynchImageView.m)

If so, it doesn't actually look like his NSURLConnection is being handled in the background. It looks like it's on the main thread.

I have used this other library in the past with success [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

If you look in this other library, they are using a proper dispatch queue for running the background.  The other class doesn't have that.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I am using the one which you used with success . It is not loading images in main thread as the ui does not get stuck as i am loaind many big images at the same time on table view and the UI dont sttuck and images loads properly but problem is until all the images are download fully no other web service call or urlconnection works and keeps on loading untill times out . But when the images are fully loaded i can call any services any number of times and they are fast .

Answer (score 2):

Make custom cell and inside of that cell, put this method

```
-(void)setImageWithUrl:(NSString *)imageUrl
{
    NSURL *urlImage = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
    [self.loadingIndicator startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSError* error = nil;
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlImage options:nil error:&error];

        if(error){
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.imgVw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
                [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
            });
        }else{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.imgVw setImage:image]; 
                [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now, call this in *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method. Put it inside cell nil condition, so that it does not called everytime you scroll.
Make comment in case of any doubt.

```
if(custCellObj == nil)
{
      NSString *imgUrl = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [custCellObj setImageWithUrl:imgUrl];
}
```

Comment: No it still does not work . Still when the images are loading . I cannot call any other service untill all the images are downloaded

Comment: What additional web-services you need to call ? Explain me. Are you reloading same web-service while images are being downloaded ? Or are you calling web-service apart from image download process ?

Comment: Any kind of services . It may be same and may be different to get some other data for other views . First i am calling a web servies that contains the url of many images . WHile the images are loading user can load any other view and that needs other service to be called but it just times out if hte images are loading ..If i wait for some time and let the images load and show fully then the other services are called fast ,

Comment: But when i checked properly even if i remove all the code and just write this 
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlImage options:nil error:&error];
only then the problem occurs . I tried to run this code in background but still the problem occurs

Comment: Are you calling other web service in background thread ? Also give me code snippet so I can get some idea. I have done this things lots of time and I have never faced this kind of issue..

Comment: Yes the services are called in background . I have updated my question with the exapmple of one service .

Comment: And have you implemented loading images as per I mentioned earlier ?

Comment: Yes i have tried implementing image loading like you said and also with asynchimageview classes